# Resizing div on hover

Tags: css

I saw this video but it seems it is not working.
 I need to resize div height `from 200px to 250px` and then make `visibility: visible;` to div inside first one.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wb7TmUR5JJw

It is not working for me is there any option without jquery?

code :

```
#album:hover{

    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    transition: All 1s ease-in-out;

}
```

Comment: is there any code?

Comment: Yes few lines didn't saw it didnt put code

Comment: Works fine - see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cmvmkjxt/3/

Comment: what is the problem...its working fine

Comment: still not working on my server nvm then

Comment: @Careless make your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.
On hover your outer div will be bigger and inner div will appear. For better effect put transition to class without hover.

html

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
div.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
div.outer:hover {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
div.inner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0; //only for better effect
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
div.outer:hover .inner {
  visibility: initial;
  opacity: 1;
}
```